# Referencing time codes of interviews in appendix

Tags: cross-referencing

For my thesis I'm analyzing interviews. As per convention, all paragraphs end with time codes (e.g. #01:01.99#), for when each person/interviewee/interviewer stops speaking and/or another begins. I'd like to reference those time code, but I don't know how. Have any of you tried something like this?

I'm also open to alternative referencing conventions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the usual `\label`–`\ref` approach if you additionally give the time code after each paragraph as follows.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\interviewtimecode}[2]{%
  \csname phantomsection\endcsname
  \def\@currentlabel{\##1:#2\#}%
  \marginpar{\@currentlabel}%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}% just for lorem ipsum filler text

\begin{document}
\section{Main Text}
X said \enquote{lorem} (\ref{one}) and \enquote{dui} (\ref{two}).

\appendix
\section{Interview One}
\lipsum*[1]\interviewtimecode{0}{1.99}\label{one}

\lipsum*[2]\interviewtimecode{1}{0.31}\label{two}
\end{document}
```

[image: The section titled "main text" reads "X said ‘lorem’ (#0:1.99#) and ‘dui’ (#1:0.31#)." Then follows a section "A. Interview One" with two paragraphs of *lorem ipsum* text and time codes in the margin after each paragraph.]

You'll find that the links jump to the end of each paragraph, which might not be ideal. It would be easier to jump to the beginning of a paragraph if the time codes were given at the beginning as well.

This could easily be extended to include a different prefix for each interview/interviewee

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\interviewprefix}[1]{%
  \def\spacelander@interviewprefix{#1}}
\newcommand*{\interviewtimecode}[2]{%
  \csname phantomsection\endcsname
  \edef\@currentlabel{\spacelander@interviewprefix.#1:#2}%
  \marginpar{\##1:#2\#}%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}% just for lorem ipsum filler text

\begin{document}
\section{Main Text}
X said \enquote{lorem} (\ref{one}) and \enquote{dui} (\ref{two}).

\appendix
\section{Interview One}
\interviewprefix{O}
\lipsum*[1]\interviewtimecode{0}{1.99}\label{one}

\lipsum*[2]\interviewtimecode{1}{0.31}\label{two}
\end{document}
```

You could also automatically generate a `\label` for each time code, which would cut out the middle-`\lable`.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for. I had to remove just the `\marginpar` command, however, because that's not how interview transcriptions look here, where I live.